# Linkedin OAuth raising 500 Internal Server Error since January 1st, 2018

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm having the error below since January 1st, 2018 when trying to login in my system with Linkedin OAuth2:

```
500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address,first-name,headline,id,last-name,picture-url,positions,public-profile-url)?format=json
```

For three days our system was having that error then on the 4th day I just removed Linkedin Login option on our website.

Today, January 11, I've tested again with the hope to enable Linkedin Login again, and the error is still there.

I've seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088337/linkedin-oauth-pictureurl-leading-to-a-500-error) and the comments give the idea that it was solved but it wasn't yet.

I don't have reputation to comment on that question, that is why I'm asking here.

Some of you know how to contact Linkedin guys to solve this problem?

It's a problem in their servers.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088337/linkedin-oauth-pictureurl-leading-to-a-500-error/48304874#48304874