# Internal Server Error for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I'm getting 500 server error after oauth2 with LinkedIn

`url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address,first-name,formatted-name,id,last-name,picture-url,public-profile-url)?format=json`

here I used python Django framework with below packages

*python-social-auth
*social-auth-app-django
*social-auth-core

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You have `python-social-auth` package? That's been deprecated for a long time now, `social-auth-app-django` and `social-auth-core` should be enough. Could you share the whole traceback?

Comment: thanks, @omab, `social-auth-app-django` use LinkedIn API v1, but since May 1 LinkedIn API v1 deprecated. So I used the manual way to do authentication with LinkedIn v2.

Answer (score 0):

In LinkedIn API Documentation it's been underlined that there are 2 types of authorization permissions: Member Authorization and Application Authorization. [LinkedIn API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/permissions?context=linkedin/context)

There is another question here that the answer suggests that it might be when OAuth client asks for more information than it's permitted to. [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088337/linkedin-oauth-pictureurl-leading-to-a-500-error/48304874#48304874)

So IMO it might be some issue about your application's permissions.